# For a std::vector, will reserve(largeNumber) need more work than reserve(smallNumber)?

Tags: c++, vector

I encounter often the case where I know that a `std::vector` will, after doing work, contain a maximum number of elements; lets say 10000. It can however easily contain much less elements, 100 for example. There is not way of telling how many elements get `.emplaced_back(...)`.

Of course, if there are 10000 calls to emplace back, the vector will reallocate several times. But much less if there are only 100 elements inserted.

My question is, would calling `.reserve(10000)` be a bad thing? Is allocating memory something that requires "linear" work or is it even constant and therefore would not have a negative impact, even if a large part of the vector is not used? What are the important points to consider if this case?

Note:
I did some profiling some time ago with the result that using `reserve(someIntermediateNumer)` -might- have advantages. The results were however not really conclusive since my program is not really deterministic (I tested on real code). My interest in this is partially also about theory.

Comment: You should perform some statistical analysis on your runtime behaviour.

Comment: Are you more likely to have a smaller are larger vector?

Comment: How much of a premium is address space?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve it is "at most linear". If you don't care about the "wasted" memory it does not hurt.

Comment: `.reserve` the maximum then `.shrink_to_fit`.

Comment: Don't bother with the shrink to fit unless you need the memory back. It may not do anything anyway.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit true, but I'd be surprised if any implementation actually did nothing.

Comment: but if you care about your memory usage you would likely not in the first place call `reserve(<large number>)` "Just to be safe"

Comment: If you make it a vector of pointers the memory overhead of the 10,000 items is constant, whatever the object.  It's also sufficiently small on modern machines that as others have said, you don't need to bother with shrinking.

Answer (score 1):

In std::vector, reserve(< large number >) does not do more work than reserve(< small number >). In both cases, a single memory allocation is performed. The negative effect is somewhere else; e.g. because your application uses more memory, it may lead to swapping at some point.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector performance may depend on your specific memory allocator. Assuming linux, It could be single system call or even all user space for some implementations depends on currently available memory. Kernel side could be different, because there is a good chance small memory block already in cache, while big size will request extra arena with sbrk or mmap. On top, page faults and swaps could more likely affect bigger chunk, but those will happen later on use.

And note All above assume that reserve is indeed request memory. Because some implementations may already have enough space allocated in constructor to ignore your request.